# Gerar executável sem console com python

Tags: python, console-application, cx-freeze

estou com um script para apagar backups antigos e compactar outros, fiz ele em python e estou tentando gerar um executável que não retorne a saída no console, para o cliente não ser surpreendido no meio de alguma venda com o console pulando na tela dele quando for executado, estou usando o cx_freeze com o silent_level 3, mas não sei por qual motivo, mesmo não aparecendo os logs no console, ele ainda abre a tela preta com o cursos piscando e quando finaliza ele fecha, segue abaixo meu código e a configuração que estou usando no setup.py

Código:

```
import os
import time
import zipfile
import datetime
import subprocess

# Diretório
srcLojamix = os.path.join('C:\\Lojamix\\Backup')

# Variaveis gerais
diasBkpsModerniza = 5
dataAtual = datetime.date.today()

# Apaga BKPs antigos do diretório padrão moderniza
subprocess.call(['forfiles', '-p', f'{srcLojamix}', '/M', '*.bak', '-d', f'-{diasBkpsModerniza}', '-c', 'cmd /c del /f /q @path'])
time.sleep(2)

# Compacta arquivos ".bak" para "backup.zip"
filezip = zipfile.ZipFile(f'{srcLojamix}\\Backup_Lojamix_{dataAtual}.zip', 'w')

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(f'{srcLojamix}'):

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.bak'):
            filezip.write(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file), f'{srcLojamix}'), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

filezip.close()

# Apaga ZIPs antigos do diretório padrão moderniza
subprocess.call(['forfiles', '-p', f'{srcLojamix}', '/M', '*.zip', '-d', f'-{diasBkpsModerniza}', '-c', 'cmd /c del /f /q @path'])
```

Setup cx freeze:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
build_options = {'packages': [], 'excludes': [], 'silent_level': 3}

base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='apaga-backups',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options},
      executables = executables)
```

Comment: aqui `subprocess.call(['forfiles',......` você chamou o [`forfiles`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) ele abre o prompt e loga cada atividade. Já tentou com [`start /b`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Tentei sim, porém ele sempre me retornava erro ao tentar executar, para entender melhor executei diretamente no terminal o forfiles com o start /b e ele me retornou o seguinte

```Start-Process : O parâmetro não pode ser processado porque o nome de parâmetro 'p' é ambíguo. Coincidências possíveis incluem:  -PassThru -PipelineVariable       -FilePath. ```